# how do you OR a whole column of bit data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, bit

I'd have a column of type "bit" and I need all the rows for that column OR'ed together. There isn't a convenient equation like SUM(column), but is there a way to do it with a single query?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean SQL ``OR`` or bit-wise ``OR`` ?

Comment: If it is bitwise use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html

Comment: You are asking for ``SUM``, which doesn't really makes sense with bits

Comment: I mean bit-wise OR, and I'm not looking for SUM.

Comment: If `BIT_OR()` doesn't work for you, please provide example data and expected output in your question. I'll down vote your question until you improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT BIT_OR(your_bit_field)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY your_bit_field
```

Doc ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-or

Comment: This doesn't quite do it, I need a "bit" type result as a single answer.

Comment: so `cast()` it, or do the `OR` in your client-side app.

Comment: This got me where I needed to go, but I had to do the real decimal to binary conversion on the client side. I was hoping for a binary result from the query, but just could find a way to get that. I also didn't need to Grouping, I just needed a single value returned. Thanks.